# how to use chronometer end to starting time? ineed 00:59 to 00:00 how can i use the code?

Tags: android, timer

how to use chronometer end to starting time? ineed 00:59 to 00:00 how can i use the code?

crm.setText("00:40");

crm.start();

crm.stop();

Comment: I don't think it can be used for countdown. You should try something else

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a cowntdown, try implementig the CountDownTimer android class. Here's a quick example:

```
  new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { //the timer runs for 30 seconds in this case
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Hope this helps!